# Determine iOS application's total disk usage/filesize

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesize, disk-access

I have an app that allows users to download files and save them to the device's internal memory. I need to be able to display the total app disk usage at any given time. I found how to check the total device disk size and usage, but not specifically the app's disk usage. How would I go about getting that same value that can be seen in the Settings -> Usage screen for the app?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `NSFileManager` to examine files and directories. Just like with a desktop app, your app has access to its sandbox and the directory and files there. The most likely place you are saving files is in your apps `Documents` directory, so you can ask `NSFileManager` to iterate over the contents of that directory for the files you are interested in, and then get attributes (like size) of those files. It's all there [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).